# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I'm using Mac os.
I installed pyscopg2 successfully (`pip3 install psycopg2`)

But when I try to import psycopg2 I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Comment: Do you have both python 2 and python 3 installed? If so, did you make sure to run python 3? Also, were you running in a virtual env but aren't now, or vice versa?

Comment: I have python 2 and 3 installed. But I'm using only python 3 (to instal and to import the psycopg2). And I didin't use the virtual env to install or import.

Answer (score 7):

You can install 'psycopg2==2.7.5' using this command:

```
pip install psycopg2==2.7.5
```

psycopg2 2.7.5 is the last version that doesn't require building from source. Although it'll throw the following warning every time it is initialized in code:

```
UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
```

So you can alternatively use `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 0):

First Install psycopg2 on both the python version, only if you don't which one you are targetting.

Command - pip install psycopg2 (for python 3)
Command - pip3 install psycopg2 (for python 2)

Although, if it does not work there is one more way as well using the .whl(wheel file)

using the wheel - pip install and from here you can download .whl file

```
pip install your.whl
```

Download the wheel file taking the version of your python in mind.

[Psycopg2 whl file](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Execute (For Python 2)

- `sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2`
- `pip install psycopg2`

For Python 3

- `sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg3`
- `pip install psycopg3`